# Using classes to access information

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I'm writing a function that takes inputs in the form of code and returns a string.

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, code, name, stock, price):
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
        self.stock = stock
        self.price = price

beer = Item(124, "beer", 200, 12.90)

print(beer.code)
```

Is there any way to get the name "beer" from its code, 124. Like you could with a dictionary? `dict = {124 : "beer"}`

Comment: You mean `beer.name`?

Comment: Right, I would like to access beer.name by only having access to beer.code if that makes sense

Comment: I would strongly recommend you consider following a basic tutorial, this is trivial stuff. You can put the instance in a dictionary, keyed by the `code`.

Comment: I do not understand what is your question? Maybe `{beer.code: beer.name}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that first you had created a list of items, something like

```
items = []
items.append(Item(124, "beer", 200, 12.90)
items.append(Item(125, "diapers", 100, 5.90)
```

Then you could use a list comprehension to find items with a given code, e.g.

```
beer = [item for item in items if item.code==124][0]
```

This assumes you can guarantee there is only one item with code 124. You could even wrap this up in a function:

```
def find_item(code):
   return [item for item in items if item.code==124][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Inventory class and do this:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, code, name, stock, price):
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
        self.stock = stock
        self.price = price

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}: {} - {} - {}'.format(self.code, self.name, self.stock, self.price)


class Inventory(object):
    _inventory = {}

    def find(self, code):
        return self._inventory.get(code)

    def add_item(self, code, name, stock, price):
        if code in self._inventory:
            raise KeyError('item with this code already present')
        self._inventory[code] = Item(code, name, stock, price)


inventory = Inventory()
inventory.add_item(124, "beer", 200, 12.90)
inventory.add_item(125, "another beer", 400, 8.10)

search = inventory.find(124)
print search
print search.name
```

output:

```
124: beer - 200 - 12.9
beer
```